# Replacing the whole village name?

Tags: r

Im  trying to replace villages names in my big data frame (all_health) using gsub, sub and others ,but I keep getting some villages not correctly changed.
for example, 
I wanted first to standardise the spelling of all villages (vlg) in the data.
e.g.:

```
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQBA","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQ","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQBA","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQA","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQBAEIL","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQBAIL","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQUBAIL","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
```

then I wanted to change the resulting village names to another name:

```
 all_health$vlg<-gsub("FALAJALQABAIL","ALKHUWAYRIYAH",all_health$vlg)
```

however, when I re-chaecked the names of the villages I noticed new different (missed up) villages such as (ALKHUWAYRIYAHBAILUBAIL) , which looks like a combination of the villages..

I have many other villages behaved just the same.

Am I using the correct function?
would anybody please help me?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using "gsub" instead of just "sub"? Could you explain what is contained in each element of all_health$vlg ? Is it single village names, or a concatenation of several names? A minimal working example would be helpful. Immediately it would seem that "FALAJALQ.*" would be a more useful pattern to match.

Comment: thank you  bdh_dtu,I used the sub function and got the same results, the vlg variable contains villages names with many different spellings , at least 200 different entries.sometimes the names are single and sometimes long and complex. the issue is that, these names are in Arabic and each clerk in the hospital( where I got the data from) has his own english spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply mapping names to other names, you don't need `sub` or `gsub`. I suspect you're running into issues because `gsub` replaces any instance within the string, and you are looking to match the whole string only.

Try doing one of these two:

```
#ensures matching of whole string by including 
#start-of-line and end-of-line characters
all_health$vlg<-gsub("^FALAJALQBA$","FALAJALQABAIL",all_health$vlg)
#and so on

#or, use %in%:
names.to.replace <- c("FALAJALQBA","FALAJALQ") #include all misspelled names
all_health$vlg[all_health$vlg %in% names.to.replace] <- "FALAJALQABAIL"
```

Comment: thank you very very much Blue Magister 
that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic way for R to figure out all of the spellings for you.  The first thing you need to do is...

```
unique(all_health$vlg)
```

Go through the resulting vector and tabulate everything into what you think the village should be. and make a new column, perhaps cvlg.  It's important that you maintain the original record because you might make a mistake fixing the names.

You might be able to use regular expressions to make it more concise but it seems possible there are spots where you cannot and need literals anyway.  Given the first part of your example, regular expressions might be able to make your code a bit more concise.  But in this kind of instance I'm tempted to just copy and paste lots of lines, use literal changes and comment them well because you'll go back some time later and want to know exactly where you changed a certain village name and how it was changed.

An alternative method that should result in good record keeping might be for you to export the unique vector into a file and make a new column in it that contains the corrected names.  You can import those two vectors from that file and change all of the names easily in R with your new vectors.  You only need to keep the ones that are wrong in the first place.

To write out the names use...

```
write.table(unique(all_health$vlg)), 'villageNameCorrections.txt', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Edit the file and label the columns "old" and "new" appropriately.  Now your R code would be.

```
correctVlg <- read.table('villageNameCorrections.txt', header = TRUE)
all_health$cvlg <- all_health$vlg
all_health$cvlg[all_health$cvlg %in% correctVlg$old] <- 
    correctVlg$new[na.omit(match(ifelse (all_health$cvlg, correctVlg$old))]
```